# How can I find the number of concurrent uses of my app on Citrix?

Tags: citrix

Is there a way under Citrix for my application to make a call to the Citrix host to find out how many copies of my application are presently running? We want to limit this in our license and we need to have a way to verify it in the code.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you could get via Citrix is to use the Powershell SDK and call Get-XASessionProcess to get a process list. The problem with this approach is you need to be a Citrix admin, and it's a fairly round about way of doing this.

If I wanted to implemented a simple concurrent limit for license enforcement I would look at two options:

1. Implement a simple web-service somewhere that my app talks to, to get a license.
2. Create a simple Windows service that tracks processes to maintain a count of concurrent instances of your app. When the configured license count is exceeded you could set a flag in a shared memory section in the global namespace. Then in your app you check this flag at startup and exit immediately when it is set.

You could track processes using WMI, e.g.

http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx

Comment: thank you. Does this mean (I know nothing about Citrix) that each user/session is a distinct session of Windows running and therefore a distinct session of my app running?

Comment: Yes each user gets their own session that is independent of other user sessions, and yes each user has their own copy of your app running in their session that won't be seen by default by other instances of your app. It is possible however to create objects in the global namespace that all sessions can see, e.g. mutexes, named pipes, shared memory sections.

Answer (score 2):

No, Citrix XenApp (which is their best-known product and probably the one you are asking about) does not offer any APIs or services that can be used for application license checking.

Comment: Follow-up question on this. Is each Citrix session a distinct VM? Or are they all running in one Windows session?

Comment: "Citrix" sessions are regular Windows user sessions. Only the access method is different (HDX aka ICA versus RDP or console). And the management tools, of course.

Comment: I can see why companies like it then - 1 license for all the users. Does Windows show a different user for each session? We could work off of user names if that is the case. thanks - dave

Comment: Umm, I suggest you take a more thorough look at Citrix and Microsoft licensing.